# Vector Spaces - Singularity

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Compute the $3 \times 3$ matrix $A^TA$, where
$$
A = 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & -1
\end{array}
\right]
\\
N(A) \text{ contains multiples of } \left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{array} \right)
\\
N(A^T) \text{ contains multiples of } \left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{array} \right)
$$
Show that it is symmetric but singular—what
vectors are in its nullspace? Removing the last column of $A$ (and last row of $A^T$)
leaves the $2 \times 2$ matrix in the upper left corner; show that it is not singular.
Could you help me with this problem?

Comment: I have added some edits to bring the image into the question to improve understanding. You still need to show some thought on this too, do you know what it means for a matrix to be singular?

Comment: @Triatticus not invertible.

Comment: And a matrix is not invertible if what is true about its determinant?

Comment: Have you done even the first step of computing $A^TA$?